# Knockout.js with CoffeeScript, Inheritance, Object Instantiation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm having trouble calling the `Test` method. I want to be able to call the child `Test` method. I'm not sure if my inheritance is correct.

WORKS

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: Save">Save</a>
```

Does Not Work

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: Test">Test</a>
```

Also.. Does Not Work

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
   data-bind="click: ContributionMappings().DebitAccount().Test">Test</a>
```

The code:

```
class DebitAccount
    constructor: () ->
        @SortOrder = ko.observable()
        @Entity = ko.observable()
        @Field = ko.observable()
        @FieldValue = ko.observable()
        @Constant = ko.observable()
        @Default = ko.observable()
        @Entity2 = ko.observable()
        @Field2 = ko.observable()

    Test: () =>
        alert 'test'

class ContributionMappings
    constructor: () ->
        @DebitAccount = ko.observable()

class Mapping
    constructor: () ->
        @ContributionMappings = ko.observable()

    Save: () =>
        alert 'save'

$ () =>
    @viewModel = new Mapping    

    # connect items with observableArrays
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

**[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/setiboka/1/edit)**

Comment: Sorry, the indention is off b/c I have to tab everything in 4 spaces for it to look like code in the WYSIWIG. Use the jsbin link above. It is a working example. Yes they are methods.

Comment: ** indentation is not related to the problem. Use the JSBin link **

Comment: http://jsbin.com/setiboka/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Classes, Inheritance, and Super](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) section of the CoffeeScript page for details on how to achieve prototype inheritance for classes.  In short, your code should probably look something like:

```
class DebitAccount
    constructor: () ->
        @SortOrder = ko.observable()
        # etc.

    Test: () =>
        alert 'test'

class ContributionMappings extends DebitAccount
    constructor: () ->
        super

class Mapping extends ContributionMappings
    constructor: () ->
        super

    Save: () =>
        alert 'save'
```

However I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve - your class names don't suggest an inheritance relationship to me.  If you're instead trying to compose the classes rather than extend them, your code would look quite similar to what you've got:

```
class DebitAccount
    constructor: () ->
        @SortOrder = ko.observable()
        #etc.

    Test: () =>
        alert 'test'

class ContributionMappings
    constructor: () ->
        @DebitAccount = ko.observable(new DebitAccount())

class Mapping
    constructor: () ->
        @ContributionMappings = ko.observable(new ContributionMappings())

    Save: () =>
        alert 'save'
```

But then you'd need to traverse the intermediate objects when referring to inner properties with your Knockout bindings:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: ContributionMappings.DebitAccount.Test">Test</a>
```